# Question on finite improper integral and its consequences

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, improper-integrals

Let $f$ be a non-negative function that satisfies the following:

- $\int_0^\infty \int_M \vert \nabla f(x,t) \vert^2 \;dxdt <\infty$
- $\int_M f(x,\cdot)\;dx=0$

where $M$ is a compact subset of $\mathbb R^2$. **Could we deduce that $f=0$?**

> What is the slightest regularity assumption that one should impose on
>   $f$ in order for the limit $\lim\limits_{t \to \infty} \int_M \vert \nabla
>  f(x,t) \vert^2 \;dx$ to exist?

Because if the limit exists then it has to be zero and since $\vert \nabla
 f(x,t) \vert^2 \ge 0$ then $\lim\limits_{t \to \infty}\int_M \vert \nabla
 f(x,t) \vert^2 \;dx=0$ yields that $f(x,\cdot)=const.$ Finally, by the second property we could conclude that $f=0$.

I would appreciate if somebody could help me complete this argument (or fix it in case I am mistaken). Any help is welcome.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Surely, your second property implies the first one? Also, the second property is sufficient all on its own to conclude that $f=0$ a.e. on $M$

Comment: @WoolierThanThou I just realized that in the way I asked, it sounds trivial. Since I had something slightly different in mind, I'll edit.